# Using custom object manager on related set

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Im trying to print out 4 entries. It works, as long I don't have any entries not published.

How can I get a queryset that only contains objects from my "published" manager?

Now I use: {% if benefit.status == "p" %} to not print those entries not published, but then the unpublished effects the slice count.

```
#views.py:

class PackageListFrontpage(ListView):
    context_object_name = "package_frontpage_list"
    template_name = "frontpage.html"
    queryset = Package.published.all().order_by('order')[:5]


#frontpage.html

{% for package in package_frontpage_list %}
<div>
    <h3>{{ package.name }} >></h3>
        <ul>
            {% for benefit in package.benefit_set.all|slice:":4" %}
              {% if benefit.status == "p" %}
                  <li><a href="{{ benefit.get_absolute_url }}">{{ benefit.name }}</a></li>
              {% endif %}
            {% empty %}
            <li>There are no published benefits in this package</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I guess there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a method on your `Package` model that returns the queryset of related benefits which are published.

```
class Package(object):
    ...
    def benefit_set_published(self):
        """
        Return the related benefits which are published
        """
        return self.benefit_set.filter(status="p")
```

Then change your template to:

```
        {% for benefit in package.benefit_set_published.all|slice:":4" %}
              <li><a href="{{ benefit.get_absolute_url }}">{{ benefit.name }}</a></li>
        {% empty %}
        <li>There are no published benefits in this package</li>
        {% endfor %}
```